# Grep result of command, redirection vs pipe

Tags: redirection, pipe

Can someone explain why the two commands below give different results?

The first pipes the output of `who` to grep, the second takes the output of `who` as a redirection.

```
~: who |grep $(tty|cut -c 6-)
my_username tty1         2016-01-22 09:56 (:0)

~: grep $(tty|cut -c 6-) <(who)
my_username pts/5        2016-01-22 11:35 (:0.0)
```

Using `color=always` as an option to grep in both cases gives the first as matching on `tty`. The second one matches on `pts/5` as expected.

The `tty | cut -c 6-` command gives me (in this instance) the `pts/5` part of `/dev/pts/5`.

I've tried using quotes (both `'` and `"`) around various parts but with no success.

I realise now that the `who -m` command gives the line I was after but the question of why the lines above are different still stands.

Answer (score 0):

The **focus** is when the shell executes the statement `$(...)`.

```
 echo $(tty)       # answers me for example /dev/pts/xx
 who | echo $(tty) # answers me `not a tty`
```

So **in a pipe process** the current version of **bash** (GNU bash, version 4.3.11) **calls another subshell**.
You can read more on the *Bash Guide for Beginners*  <sup>[[1](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_04)],[[2](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html#sect_08_02_03)]</sup> .

Do not let the title mislead you... it's full of good information not only for the beginners.